# ADB shell gets "stuck" connecting to Samsung S10, must open other ADB shell to "unstuck" it

Tags: adb, linux, samsung-galaxy-s-10

On Ubuntu, I often use `adb shell` and other operations such as `adb push` and `adb pull` over a USB cable.

On Nexus 5 it always worked perfectly. But since I switched to Samsung S10e I have this very surprising problem:

1. I open a terminal on my laptop, run `adb shell`.
2. I type normally in ADB shell (`ls`, typing enter, etc), the expected output appears.
3. As I continue typing, suddenly my typed character is not shown, as if the USB connection was stuck.
4. I have found a strange workaround: When that happens, I open another terminal and run `adb shell` in it.
5. Immediately, that "unstucks" the first terminal, and the "stucked" characters appear.
6. Now I can use the first terminal again, until it gets stuck again.
7. When that happens, I type a few characters in the second terminal, and that solves the problem again.
8. Inevitably as I repeat the trick several times, the second terminal gets stuck too.
9. When that happens, I open a third terminal, and that "unstucks" the first and second terminals.
10. Etc. Sometime I need to open a fourth terminal.

This also happens with other ADB commands.

Question: How to investigate the problem? Is there any Android setting that could mitigate or even solve the problem?

Comment: only when battery is 100% or always?

Comment: @alecxs: Always.

Comment: Hm.. i have this when connected adb over wifi when device goes to sleep

Comment: i guess we can assume the reason is related to this? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/216103

Comment: @alecxs: The moisture problem started 16 days ago. On the opposite, the present problem has existed since the day I bought the phone (several months ago).

Comment: any news on this? I'm having the same problem with a Galaxy S9