# "Moisture has been detected" even after 2 weeks, also in safe mode

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-10

Two weeks ago my Samsung Galaxy S10e got a bit wet while in my pocket under heavy rain. The phone did not *go inside water*, but it was pretty wet.

Since then, I got this message from time to time when charging:

> Unplug charger
>   Moisture has been detected. Unplug the charger and wait until both the charger and USB port are dry.

1. Yesterday, I could not even charge my phone once, because the message appeared every single time I tried.
2. I let the phone at the output my [air conditioner in dehumidifier mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehumidifier#Conventional_air_conditioners) for the whole night.
3. Still the same problem.
4. I tried with 3 different USB cables, and also 3 different power sources.
5. The charger port looks perfectly clean.
6. I don't have a wireless charger.
7. The message (and vibration) appears even in safe mode and in Emergency mode, and also when the phone is off.

In recovery mode the message does not appear, but the phone does not charge (when I left the phone in recovery mode for one hour, the battery went from 53% to 48%, even though the USB cable was connected).

I believe that the message is erroneous, I can't see how moisture could subsist after two weeks and a night of dehumidification. How can I fix the problem?

I live in Japan, where outside air humidity is high, maybe that's a factor?
My phone is rooted, if that can help.

Comment: One night next to an air conditioner is not very much. The common method for drying a smartphone is placing it in a bag of dry rice leaving it there for some days.

Comment: Hair Dryer on cool setting directed at the port. Mine dried within 4h. Same situation for me, pocket, rain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few more weeks and the message disappeared.

I guess some part of the phone was still humid despite all of that drying.

Conclusion: Let you phone dry as long as it takes.